# Video Tutorial for Kohana3?

Tags: kohana, kohana-3

Is there any Video Tutorial for the Kohana3 ? or some easy way to study Kohana3.
some one to tell me RTFM  , but I'm so stupid indeed .
I 'm searching the video tutorial for a while but gain nothing.
who can help me...

Comment: The [official docs](http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/) are not too bad, and you might want to have a look at the [unofficial WIKI](http://kerkness.ca/kowiki/doku.php), but I don't think there is a good video tutorial.

Comment: Documentation, blogs, Wiki @ kerkness.ca are useful resources. IMO trying to learn programming/tools is not the best idea. What is the point of watching them?

Comment: What exactly are you having trouble with? I'd be happy to answer some questions for you.

Answer (score 0):

Not really for Kohana, I've looked around quite a bit but haven't found anything.
Best thing is really just to start using it and try to use the docs there is (and doin't forget the api docs which usually is better).
Once you get to know the available docs you don't really need the video.

If you get stuck, shoot out a question about that instead and you'll get help fast.

Good luck!